# migration to bluetooth 3.1

Tags: c, bluetooth

I have a project which uses Bluetooth 2.1 code and We want to migrate to 3.0 code in c programming.

**Questions:**

1. How to migrate from 2.0 to 3.1 or possibly 4.0 in term of writing code?
2. Is there any tutorial or link which describes how to change the code that accept bluetooth 3.1 code?
3. Also I am wondering do I need to change the firmware or hardware to make it compatiable to 3.0?

Comment: What is your current platform and API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main change in Bluetooth 3.0 added the ability to use co-located wifi hardware to send data at higher rates (but it goes over the wifi link, not the bluetooth link).  This is mostly a hardware / firmware change, and I don't think it's very commonly used.

Bluetooth 4.0 adds a completely different low energy mode that is not compatible with previous BT modes (although you can have hardware that does both modes).  This is also a mainly hardware and firmware change.

What are you trying to accomplish by porting your code to a different version?

Comment: I have been told to investigate whether we can change our software code to make it BTv3. The hardware supports BT+HS.  if we established the link over BT protocol like L2CAP then transmit data over MAC/PHY?